# An unexpected severe error has occurred in Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

My Jdeveloper is continuously prompting me with this error popup window.
[image]

The error details is as follows:-

[image]

The details of the error message is as follows:-

```
Exception while updating action Block Selection
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/javatools/editor/EditorSelectionColumns
  o.i.ceditor.CodeEditorController.update(CodeEditorController.java:462)
  o.i.controller.IdeAction.updateAction(IdeAction.java:787)
  o.i.controller.IdeAction.updateAction(IdeAction.java:749)
  o.i.view.View.updateAction(View.java:390)
  o.i.view.View.updateToolbarActions(View.java:384)
  o.i.view.View.updateVisibleActions(View.java:214)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow$UpdateVisibleActions.fireUpdate(NbMainWindow.java:1794)
  com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow$UpdateVisibleActions.actionPerformed(NbMainWindow.java:1779)
  jx.s.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
  jx.s.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
  j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
  j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
  j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
  j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  j.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
  o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
  o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
  j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I cant figure it out what is the problem. It worked few times by cancelling the pop up. But I think it's better to find a solution for it.

Comment: Need to know version, of course. Check My Oracle support for more info. Usually saving and restarting fixes this - for a while. Might look at upgrading depending on version. Editor stuff looks like a ui bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly regular screen in jDeveloper, I get it at least twice a day. I click save and exit (which does nothing) and continue working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, by clicking on "save all files and exit" I could continue working but when I restarted the program I had lost all the changes.
The solution was to reinstall Jdeveloper again.